# Python: Plotting a Histogram Downward

Tags: python, histogram

I am trying to plot a histogram from a set of user input values.

Okay, I updated my code to this:

```
number1 = ""
number2 = ""
number3 = ""
number4 = ""

numbers = input("Enter a string of positive integers separated by spaces: ")
print(" ")
newNum = numbers.split()

line = 0
col = 0
lines = int(max(newNum))
length = len(newNum)

while line<lines:
    col = 0
    while col<length:
        if line<int(newNum[col]):
            print('* ', end = '')
        else:
            print('  ')
        col = col+1
    line = line+1
    print("")
```

But when I run the code I get this:

```
Enter a string of positive integers separated by spaces: 1 3 20 5

* * * * 

* * * 

* * * 


* * 


* *
```

What am I missing now to get my histogram to print like this? Also, why is it not printing the values to 20?

```
Enter a string of positive integers separated by spaces: 1 3 20 5

* * * *
  * * *
  * * *
    * *
    * *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
    *
```

Comment: What have you tried? And where are you stuck? Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice?).

Comment: The above code is as far as I've gotten. I'm just not sure how to get it to flip.

Comment: I do not know your application but would it be an option to use scipy or matplotlib for bargraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example you never reset `col`; you probably should set `col=0` each time before starting the second while loop:

```
while line<lines:
    col=0
    while col<length:
        ...
```

otherwise the inner loop runs once only.

a nested `for` loop might be more natural for that...

and when printing inside a row, you want no endline character; you should use `print('* ', end='')` and use an empty `print()` at the end of every row.

then you should convert your numbers to integers as soon as possilbe:

```
newNum = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]
```

otherwise `max(newNum)` will return `'5'` - the highest digit in the string.

and you are still missing and `end=' '` in the `print('  ')` statement.

this should fix your issues.

---

a more elegant version - counting down the list of numbers until the list consists of zeroes only:

```
def vertical_histo(number_list):
    rest = number_list
    while any(rest):
        print(' '.join('*' if i else ' ' for i in rest))
        rest = [i-1 if i else 0 for i in rest]

# to get your example, call this function with:
vertical_histo(number_list=(1, 3, 20, 5)))
```

`rest` holds the amount of `*` you still need to display for each column

```
rest = (1, 3, 20, 5)  # first round
rest = [0, 0, 17, 2]  # after 3 rounds
# ...etc
rest = [0, 0, 1, 0]   # last round
rest = [0, 0, 0, 0]   # when done
```

then these are shifted down (right) by one in every iteration.

```
' '.join('*' if i else ' ' for i in ones)
```

this then creates a string with a `'*'` for every entry in `rest` that is not zero yet. otherwise it will add a `' '`.

`any(rest)` is `True` as long as `ones` contains non-zero entries.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to program it manually.

For example, if we're at a line that is less than or below the element.
This rough sample should guide you:

```
line = 0
col = 0
lines = max(newNum)
length = len(newNum)

return    
while line<lines:
    while col<length:
        if line<newNum[col]:
            print "* ",
        else:
            print "  ",
        col = col+1
    line = line+1
    print ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all! With this code I was able to solve the question:

```
number1 = ""
number2 = ""
number3 = ""
number4 = ""

numbers = input("Enter a string of positive integers separated by spaces: ")
print(" ")
newNum = [int(i) for i in numbers.split()]

line = 0
col = 0
lines = int(max(newNum))
length = len(newNum)

while line<lines:
    col = 0
    while col<length:
        if line<int(newNum[col]):
            print('* ', end = '')
        else:
            print('  ', end = '')
        col = col+1
    line = line+1
    print("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's give the name `data` to a list containing the depth of each column in your histogram

```
data = [3, 5, 2]
```

How many rows are you going to print?

```
nrows = max(data) #=> 5
```

If you ask Python to count your rows, Python starts from `0` and stops at `nrows-1`

```
for row in range(nrows): print(row) #=> 0 1 2 3 4
```

So the row no. 3 has index `row` equal to `2` and row no. 4 has index `3`, now think of the first column of the histogram, you have to print 3 `'+'`,
this means a `'+'` in row no.3 (i.e., `row=2`) and nothing in row no.4  (i.e., `row=3`)

```
'+' if (data[col] > row) else ' '
```

After this analysis we can write the function that computes the histogram

```
def histogram(data):
    return '\n'.join(
        ''.join('+' if depth>row else ' ' for depth in data)
        for row in range(max(data)))
```

and we are ready to test it

```
In [36]: def histogram(data):
    ...:         return '\n'.join(
    ...:             ''.join('+' if depth>row else ' ' for depth in data)
    ...:             for row in range(max(data)))
    ...: 

In [37]: print(histogram((3,4,5,6)))
++++
++++
++++
 +++
  ++
   +

In [38]:
```

Or, shorter,

```
In [38]: def histogram(d, nl='\n'.join, jn=''.join):
...:     return nl(jn('+'if n>r else' 'for n in d)for r in range(max(d)))
...: 

In [39]: print(histogram((3,4,5,6)))
++++
++++
++++
 +++
  ++
   +

In [40]:
```